# Magento2 : How to display custom values in checkout page

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, knockout

I am working on checkout page, I have pass some array values to checkout config provider.

How to get those values in knockout JS and display by knockout html.

Want to display all applied codes in checkout payment step.

I have passed values to config provider by below code

```
public function getConfig()
    {
        return $this->getAppliedGiftCards();
    }

    public function getAppliedGiftCards()
    {
        $quoteId = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getId();
        $giftcardCodes = $this->quoteFactory->getGiftCardCollection($quoteId);
        $config = [];
        foreach ($giftcardCodes as $giftcardCode){
            $config['payment']['applied_giftcard'][$giftcardCode->getCode()] = $giftcardCode->getCode();
        }
        return $config;
    }
```

Get values in Js by below code

```
var configValues = window.checkoutConfig.payment;
var applied_giftcard = ko.observable(configValues.applied_giftcard);
```

How to render passed config array value to knockout template.

Comment: on which section of payment method you want to show your data?

Comment: I want to display just before discount code apply block

Answer (score 2):

You want to add `window.checkoutConfig` then you need to create a plugin on `Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider`.

Create  after method on `getConfig()`  **afterGetConfig** and add  pass you array as json value.

Create `di.xml` at `app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/etc`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider">
        <plugin name="add_new_variable_checkout_config" type="{VendorName}{ModuleName}\Plugin\DefaultConfigProviderPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**Plugin class**

```
namespace {VendorName}\{ModuleName}\Plugin;

class DefaultConfigProviderPlugin
{

 
    public function afterGetConfig(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject,
    $output     
    ) {
        $output['my_custom_data'] = json_encode(array('name'=> 'john', 'age' => '10'));
    return $output;
    }
 
}
```

Now, you want to render this data to payment section then ,Please copy

`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment.js`

to your theme level

`app/design/frontend/{Venoder}/{Themename}/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/payment.js`

OR Rewrite `module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment.js`

and  new function  `getmyCustomdata` name for getting value **from the config value**

```
    ......
    getmyCustomdata: function () {
        return window.checkoutConfig.my_custom_data;
    }
```

Now, you have to print **getmyCustomdata** value to knockjs HTML template `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/payment.html`

So, copy this file to to your theme level.

`app/design/frontend/{Venoder}/{Themename}/Magento_Checkout/web/template/payment.html`

At this payment.html bind data  using  `<span  data-bind="text: getmyCustomdata()"></span>`

Comment: check my updated question.

Comment: I have follow same but not working.